# bootstrap datepicker with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out this [datepicker plugin](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). i can't seem to get it to work. Is bootstrap not compatible with jquery 1.9+ ?

```
<div class="alert alert-error" id="alert">
    <strong>Oh snap!</strong>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
              Start date
              <a href="#" class="btn small" id="date-start" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-20">Change</a>
          </th>
          <th>
              End date
              <a href="#" class="btn small" id="date-end" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="2012-02-25">Change</a>
          </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="date-start-display">2012-02-20</td>
          <td id="date-end-display">2012-02-25</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

any idea what i'm missing? [Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/jbDUe/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go .. http://jsfiddle.net/jbDUe/2/
you forgot to load the datepicker-plugin.js.

I have added it as an external resource and everything is working.

Use this GitHub CDN to load your file in jsFiddle external resources:
https://raw.github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
var startDate = new Date(2012,1,20);
var endDate = new Date(2012,1,25);

$('#date-start')
    .datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()){
            $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date must be before the end date.');
        } else {
            $('#alert').hide();
            startDate = new Date(ev.date);
            $('#date-start-display').text($('#date-start').data('date'));
        }
        $('#date-start').datepicker('hide');
    });
$('#date-end')
    .datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
            $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The end date must be after the start date.');
        } else {
            $('#alert').hide();
            endDate = new Date(ev.date);
            $('#date-end-display').text($('#date-end').data('date'));
        }
        $('#date-end').datepicker('hide');
    });
```

Comment: oh thanks, i just copied the whole plugin and put it in the JS section.

Comment: Yes but you did that after the call to .datepicker() that is why the code could not fined the method datepicker().

Comment: If that helps be kind enough to mark the answer as correct by checking the green V mark so others can see it first.